# Como trocar termos em uma Expression?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, expressões

Baseado na seguinte resposta em: **[How to convert an expression tree to a partial SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891426)**, estou usando uma classe herdada de `ExpressionVisitor` para tentar tratar algumas condições em minhas expressões.

Exemplo de uso:

```
var pessoaId = 1; // dessa variável preciso trocar na expressão por parâmetro 
                  // e retornar no dicionario o nome do parâmetro e valor do mesmo.

var expression = ((pessoa, telefones) => pessoa.Id == pessoaId);

var queryFilterParser = new QueryFilterParser();
var paramValues = queryFilterParser.Parse(expression);
```

E para isso tenho:

```
public class QueryFilterParser : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> ParamValues { get; private set; }
    ...
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression constantExpression)
    {
        // Em: (pessoa.Id == value(GenericDAO.Tests.DAOTests+<>c__DisplayClass0).pessoaId)
        // trocar value(GenericDAO.Tests.DAOTests+<>c__DisplayClass0).pessoaId por
        // @pessoaId

        // obter o valor e saber o nome do parâmetro para alimentar o dicionário
        return base.VisitConstant(constantExpression);
    }
    ...
}
```

Preciso através disso retornar um dicionário contendo o nome de um parâmetro e seu valor para o `Dictionary<string, object>`. Então é necessário trocar o termo dentro da expressão, deixando uma string no formato de um parâmetro SQL e obter o valor da `ConstantExpression`.

Como isso pode ser feito?

---

### Edição:

Para obter o valor e o nome do parâmetro estou fazendo o seguinte no método `VisitMember`:

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpression)
{
    ...
    else if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
    {
        var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        var constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
        var value = (memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo).GetValue(constantExpression.Value);

        ParamValues.Add(name, value);

        this.Visit(constantExpression);
        return memberExpression;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Falta agora substituir a constant dentro da expressão pelo nome do parâmetro. Como fazer ?**

---

### Edição 2:

Aparentemente essa resposta de Jon Skeet resolve o problema, mas comigo não funcionou: **[How to get the value of a ConstantExpression which uses a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998707)**.

Pelo o que entendi, `return Expression.Constant("@" + name, typeof(string));` deveria funcionar.

Uma expressão simples contendo `{@pessoaId}` é gerado mas não é retornado como no exemplo que ele deu o termo alterado.

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpression)
{
    ...
    else if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
    {
        var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        var constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
        var value = (memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo).GetValue(constantExpression.Value);

        ParamValues.Add(name, value);

        // pelo exemplo de Jon Skeet isso resolveria ...
        return Expression.Constant("@" + name, typeof(string)); 
    }
    ...
}
```

**Como isso pode ser feito?**

Comment: `Expression.Constant` serve para armazenar um valor constante. A substituição feita na sua edição faz a expressão original se trasformar em algo como `(pessoa, telefones) => pessoa.Id == "@pessoaId"`.

Answer (score 2):

O processo torna-se bem mais simples se o construtor de comandos SQL for baseado em `ExpressionVisitor`, como em ***[DefaultSqlQueryGenerator](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Relational/Query/Sql/DefaultSqlQueryGenerator.cs)*** do **EF 7**, e que segue o apresentado por Jon Skeet em sua resposta em **[How to convert an expression tree to a partial SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query/7891426#7891426)**.

Nessa estratégia as complicações desapareceram.

Sobre

> a expressão original se trasformar em algo como `(pessoa, telefones) => pessoa.Id == "@pessoaId"`

Não é possível pois uma expressão é imutável, então não é possível alterar seus membros como eu queria. O que eu poderia fazer é criar uma expressão nova para retornar, mas tratar isso em todos os métodos ***Visitors***.

Mas como dito na edição 2 da pergunta, realmente `Expression.Constant("@" + name, typeof(string))` retorna `"@Name"`.